# OptionParse in Ruby and params not starting with '-'

Tags: ruby, optparse

I want to have params like this:

```
program dothis --additional --options
```

and:

```
program dothat --with_this_option=value
```

and I can't get how to do that. The only thing I managed to do is to use params with `--` at the beginning.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To handle positional parameters using OptionParser, first parse the switches using OptionParser and then fetch the remaining positional arguments from ARGV:

```
# optparse-positional-arguments.rb
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: #{__FILE__} [command] [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = true
  end

  opts.on("--list x,y,z", Array, "Just a list of arguments") do |list|
    options[:list] = list
  end
end.parse!
```

On executing the script:

```
$ ruby optparse-positional-arguments.rb foobar --verbose --list 1,2,3,4,5

p options
# => {:verbose=>true, :list=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]}

p ARGV
# => ["foobar"]
```

The `dothis` or `dothat` commands can be anywhere. The `options` hash and `ARGV` remains the same regardless:

```
 # After options
 $ ruby optparse-positional-arguments.rb --verbose --list 1,2,3,4,5 foobar

 # In between options
 $ ruby optparse-positional-arguments.rb --verbose foobar --list 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: This way I cannot be sure if `dothis` or `dothat` was the first parameter, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can think of it like `script [command] [options]`. Wherein command and options are positionally interchangeable. So it could also be `script [options] [command]`. Does that work for you?

Comment: and what would be a good way of getting possible commands into the usage string? just stick it into the `opts.banner`?